measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{Q}$, s.t. $\mu([0,q)) = q$ for all rationals $q$

Does there exist a measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{Q}$, such that all intervals are measurable and $\mu([0,q)) = q$ for any positive rational number $q$? Prove or disprove

Assume it existed. Then, by restriction on a compact interval $T$, $\mu|_{T}$ is a finite measure. Firstly, we have that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $m([0,q)) = q < \epsilon \implies \mu([0,q)) = q < \epsilon$ whenever $0 \leq q < \epsilon$ is a positive rational.
Similarly, if $m(O) < \epsilon$  for an open set $O$, then as $O = U_k I_k$, where $I_k$ are disjoint intervals, we get $\mu(O) = \sum_k \mu(I_k)< \epsilon$ (by density of rationals).
Now, I'm not sure how to extend this to general Borel sets to conclude that $\mu << m$, which is nice because $\mu(\mathbb{Q}) = 0 = m(\mathbb{Q})$ - contradicting the fact that $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathbb{Q}$. (I'm guessing that absolute continuity on generating sets is not enough?)
Part of my confusion is that I'm not sure what it means by if "there exists a measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{Q}$" - is this saying that the support of $\mu$ is $\mathbb{Q}$ (but that can't be because the support is closed, whereas $\mathbb{Q}$ is not)? Is it then saying that $\mu$ is of the form $\sum_{q_k \in \mathbb{Q}} a_k 1_{\{q_k\}}$?

Why is $m([0,q))<\epsilon$?

@md2perpe sorry, I corrected the typo.

Here's a simpler approach.
You can easily prove that $\mu([a,b])=b-a$ when $0<a<b\in \mathbb{Q}$. I will leave that as an exercise.
I claim that for every singleton $q$, $\mu(\{q\})=0$.
Indeed, let $q_n = q-\frac{1}{n}$. Clearly, $\mu(\{q\})\leq \mu([q_n,q]) = q-q_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.
Now, by countable aditivity we have $\mu(\mathbb{Q})=0$, but then $\mu([0,q])=0$ for all $q$, by contradiction.

Nice answer! Small nitpick: you can technically only prove that $\mu([a, b]) = b - a$ when $0 < a < b$, since the question doesn't say anything about the behaviour on the negative rationals. Of course this doesn't affect the argument!

@IzaakvanDongen Good point!

"A measure on $\mathbb Q$" presumably means a measure on the measurable space $(\mathbb Q, \mathcal A)$ where $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.  Since all intervals are measurable, singletons $\{r\}$ are measurable: if you don't count a closed interval of length $0$ as an "interval", you can say $$\{r\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(r-\frac{1}{n}, r + \frac{1}{n}\right)$$
And then, as in Yanko's answer, countable additivity gives you the rest.
